# Creating a surface plot from an Unstructured grid vtk file using Vedo

Tags: vtk

I have an unstructured grid vtk file that contains three different types of cells (Tetrahedral, Wedge and Hexahedral). This file contains multiple Scalars (8 attributes such as Pressure, Temperature e.t.c.) and a Single Vector (U,V,W) and I am trying to create a surface plot from this file for a Scalar or Vector at a time using the Vedo python wrapper for vtk. The vtk file contains a scalar or vector value for each cell, including the point coordinates.

I have read the documentation over and over, with examples here https://vtkplotter.embl.es/content/vtkplotter/index.html. These are the things that I have tried with the challenge that I am having with each method:

Method 1: Loading the file as a TetMesh

```
vp = Plotter()
test = load('Case_60.vtk')
vp.show(test)
```

This method doesn't plot Scalar Values and only shows points. No Solid Surface. Tried using a cuttertool() with it , it throws an error saying non-Tetrahedral Cell Encountered.

Method 2: Using the UGrid

```
ug = UGrid('Case_60.vtk')
show(ug)
```

This method plots as surface with a solid color. Does not seem to be picking the Scalars.

What is the proper way for me to display surface plot and display the scalar value for each cell? Is Vedo able to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify which array is to be used for coloring, e.g.:

```py
from vedo import *
ug = UGrid(datadir+'limb_ugrid.vtk')
print(ug.getArrayNames())
ug.selectCellArray('chem_0')
show(ug, axes=True)
```

if this doesn't work for your mesh please submit an issue [here](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/issues).